# Python arrange numbers with corresponding string

Tags: python-2.7

I want to sort float numbers in descending order with the corresponding string. For e.g.

```
Mass=[10,45.5,56.7,34.7,12,8.2,56,78.5,5.5,21.5]
Name=['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A7','A8','A9','A10']
```

Now I want to arrange mass in descending order so that it will give me

```
A8=78.5, A3=56.7, A7=56.....
```

How can I do it in python?

Many thanks

Cheers,

-Viral

Comment: Did you even try simple sorting?

Comment: yes. I did. sorted(Mass,reverse=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `zip` those, putting the mass in the first place, then `sort` them in reversed order.

```
for m, n in sorted(zip(Mass, Name), reverse=True):
    print n, m
```

Output:

```
A8 78.5
A3 56.7
A7 56
...
```

Comment: @viralparekh Sorry for bugging you, but didn't you just accept this answer? Now its unaccepted again. What happened?

Answer (score 0):

This code returns exactly what you want.

```
Mass=[10,45.5,56.7,34.7,12,8.2,56,78.5,5.5,21.5]
Name=['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A7','A8','A9','A10']

for m,n in sorted(zip(Mass, Name), key=lambda pair: pair[0], reverse=True):
  print "%s=%s," % (n, m),
```

> A8=78.5, A3=56.7, A7=56, A2=45.5, A4=34.7, A10=21.5, A5=12, A1=10,
>   A6=8.2, A9=5.5,

You can use join if you don't need the colon at end.

Comment: `key=lambda pair: pair[0]` does nothing at all.

Comment: Using this approach you can specify another key if you have more then two lists. Also it less depends on arguments order in zip function (and you can change `zip(Mass, Name)` to `zip(Name, Mass)` without any frustration).